# How can I get a post to be undeleted once I've fixed the issues?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/271955/why-has-the-adoption-of-abac-been-so-slow/273483#273483) on ABAC adoption was deleted with an hour of my posting it. The moderator claimed it missed the point of the question so I reworked it to be clearer. The post is factual and the area is one I've been working in for 15 years. How can I notify Schroeder so he can reconsider the delete action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta is the place to post a request for reconsideration.

The problem, as I said, was not that it was not factual, but rather that it didn't answer the question. I am not questioning your expertise, as I said that the content was great information. Just posted in the wrong place.

Comment: Given that I added a whole new section that addresses the question specifically, I'd like you to reconsider. Also note that the question itself is loaded. How do you measure adoption? WHere do you draw the line between externalized authorization (ABAC) and baked-in ABAC?

Comment: Yes, you have addressed my concerns and it has been undeleted.